# Tango Unity Examples Not Building

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I have been trying to build and run the tango unity example on my new tango device and it doesn't seem to be working. As soon as the app launched the app crashes on my device. It just says `Unfortunetely, Unity Examples has stopped.`

I also tried to run a simple app with Tango AR camera and got the same result.

I am running Unity 5.4.0f3 (64-bit) with Android Studio 2.1.2. I installed all the tools on the Surface Book (Windows 10) on `8/1/2016`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on the Tango developers group on G+, Tango SDK does not support Unity 5.4 yet, you need to download 5.3.

> Hi Devs,
>
> Unity released version 5.4 last week.  As a result, Tango development is broken.  The team is aware of the issue is currenlty working to address the issue this month. In the meantime, the only workaround is to stay on Unity 5.3.
>
> Thank you for your patience everyone.

https://plus.google.com/+ProjectTango/posts/N9DEz2RKZSb